# Laravel: Test post with real file

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I'm using laravel `5.6`. I'm trying to test a `post` form that need a `file`.
So I wrote that

```
$file = new \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile(base_path() . '/tests/samples/Cylinder.stl', 'Cylinder.stl');

$response = $this->post( route('attachments.store' ) , [
    'file' => $file,
    'attachable_id' => $this->threedviews->id,
    'attachable_type' => 'App\ThreeDView',
]);
```

But when I `dd( $this->app['session.store'] )`, I get

```
#bags: array:1 [
        "default" => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag {#1198
          #messages: array:1 [
            "file" => array:1 [
              0 => "The file failed to upload."
            ]
          ]
          #format: ":message"
        }
      ]
```

When I use the form manualy, everything is working well.
Also the `$file` seems strange

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#43
  -test: false
  -originalName: "Cylinder.stl"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -error: 0
  ...
}
```

The `test` flag is set to false, is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: What does your `laravel.log` file say? The log file should contain a specific exception, like file permissions or invalid path.

Comment: @NirajShah The `laravel.log` is empty because the app is not failing, it's just that the `POST` is returning an unexpected error message but laravel is not failing. Or maybe the `log` is by default somewhere else for the tests?

Comment: There must be a more specific error message being generated somewhere other than `The file failed to upload.` - that appears to be the message returned by `Validator`.